# Can we do something about font ambiguity of 0 (zero) vs o (lower case 'O')?

Tags: bug, design

[This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/133516/34716) uses the well-known phrase "game zero", except it uses a numeric '0' (Game 0).

I had to read the line several times, before realizing what was being said. Then I even tried to edit the post to "fix" the o into a zero, before realizing what had happened.

Can we do something about this? Zeros are fairly ubiquitous in our hobby, so I expect this to come up a lot.

Comment: For whatever reason the 0 is perfectly distinct on my phone. (Chrome, Android, both recent versions.) Maybe its system serif font is doing that.

Comment: Yes, this is a problem: https://imgur.com/a/KjlWuGI

Comment: Usually I'm able to guess what is meant based on context, but I can definitely agree that they look very similar in my desktop browser.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning this in the thread about the roll out of the site's new look.